# Fast, efficient way to remove rows from large Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to remove rows from a large Pandas DataFrame that contains analytics data based on actions/events users have done on a website. All streams of user actions begin with the `start` event, and finish with the `end` event. I want to find all users who have done a particular event (such as `signed up` - index 13 in the example dataframe) and remove all events after that event until (and including) the `end` event. So in this example, `viewed blog post`, `page view`, `visited site`, `ad campaign hit`, `viewed blog post`, `visited site`, `page view`, and `end` would have to be removed from the dataframe.

```
In [26]: data
Out[26]: 
    event            user
0   start            user1
1   visited blog     user1
2   page view        user1
3   visited blog     user1
4   viewed blog post user1
5   ad campaign hit  user1
6   page view        user1
7   visited site     user1
8   visited blog     user1
9   viewed blog post user1
10  visited site     user1
11  page view        user1
12  signed up        user1
13  viewed blog post user1
14  page view        user1
15  visited site     user1
16  ad campaign hit  user1
17  viewed blog post user1
18  visited site     user1
19  page view        user1
20  end              user1
```

I've tried to do this in a number of ways - using `np.where()` to identify the correct rows or

```
removal_starts_at = data[(data.user == 'user1') & (data.event == 'signed up')]
removal_ends_at = data[(data.user == 'user1') & (data.event == 'end')]
data[data.user == 'user1'].drop(data.index[removal_start_at+1:removal_ends_at+1], inplace=True)
```

However, this is really slow! It's takes ~20 seconds per user. I have 1000s of users, so this is not efficient. I'd like something that does it in a much quicker fashion if possible.

Another issue I discovered as I was writing up this question:
If I don't include `[data.user == 'user1']` to subset the dataframe, it goes crazy and takes up all the memory on the computer. If I do include it, it doesn't actually do the subsetting and gives me a warning about `SettingWithCopy`.

I'm relatively new to Pandas, so it's quite likely that there's a simpler way to do it and that I'm just doing it entirely incorrectly. Ideas I've thought about are using `MultiIndex` to find the combination of user & event directly or perhaps subsetting in a more efficient way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the idea is you have lots of users in one dataframe.  So I've expanded it to have 2 users.  If that's right, then something like this ought to be pretty fast:

```
df['keep'] = np.where( df['event'] == 'start', 1, np.nan )
df['keep'] = np.where( df['event'].shift() == 'signed up', 0, df['keep'] )
df['keep'] = df['keep'].ffill()

               event   user  keep
0              start  user1     1
1       visited blog  user1     1
2          page view  user1     1
3          signed up  user1     1
4   viewed blog post  user1     0
5          page view  user1     0
6                end  user1     0
7              start  user2     1
8       visited blog  user2     1
9          signed up  user2     1
10  viewed blog post  user2     0
11               end  user2     0

df[df['keep']==1]

          event   user  keep
0         start  user1     1
1  visited blog  user1     1
2     page view  user1     1
3     signed up  user1     1
7         start  user2     1
8  visited blog  user2     1
9     signed up  user2     1
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! In general, is it faster to use numpy functions to search through Pandas dataframes than built in Pandas functionality? Also, is there any way that indexing smartly (rather than treating them as just row numbers) would have helped in my case?

Comment: I'm not sure b/c I don't know what you were doing before.  Were you implementing your code with a big loop and cycling through each user?  If so, the problem with that is you're doing an `if/where` type of operation way too many times.  If you have 500 users, looping through the users is going to take 500x as long as doing it the way I did (one operation on ALL users, no looping).  Numpy and pandas functions shouldn't vary much in speed, but pure numpy operations (numpy functions on numpy arrays) will be faster when you have that option.

Comment: I was using the `pd.apply()` function which I guess is equivalent to looping over all users. It makes much more sense to do it to the entire df at one pass if you can.

Answer (score 3):

I would just store the index that I wanted and then use a slice from there.

```
In [15]: idx = data.query('user=="user1" and event=="signed up"').index[0]

In [16]: data[:idx+1]
Out[16]: 
               event   user
0              start  user1
1       visited blog  user1
2          page view  user1
3       visited blog  user1
4   viewed blog post  user1
5    ad campaign hit  user1
6          page view  user1
7       visited site  user1
8       visited blog  user1
9   viewed blog post  user1
10      visited site  user1
11         page view  user1
12         signed up  user1
```